# BottomSheetFragment is Do not working as expected in Fragment. Android Studio Java XML

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have written code for bottom pop in fragment view.

.JAVA

```
languages_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putString("key", "2");
  bottomSheetFragment.setArguments(args);
  bottomSheetFragment.show(getParentFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.getTag());
  }
});
```

.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".BottomSheetFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewData"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClosePopup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Close"
            android:layout_gravity="end"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="English"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="English"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="English"/>

    </RadioGroup>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

for this I am getting output like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHHhr.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B5g0.jpg)

but, when i do this code in activity

```
btnShowPopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("key", "2");
    bottomSheetFragment.setArguments(args);
    bottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.getTag());
  }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37tot.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPsCw.jpg)

here I want to output as same as activity,
when we click the
btnShowPopup btn then we can see the background of that activity

i need same when we click on languages_btn btn then we need to able to see fragment in background.

I use only Java XML Android Studio

Comment: this is not enough code to understand the problem. Add more code and explain properly. Your BottomNavigationView XML, code where you init your BottomNavigation.